# Session only works one time spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

When i successfully logged in (using logincontroller), I can see the session attribute "user" value.

FOR EXAMPLE:

-- in logincontroller --

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logIn(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map){
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("Login function is called.");
        List<UsersModule> list = loginModuleService.getLoginDetails(email,password);
        UsersModule foundEntity = new UsersModule();
        HttpSession session = null;
        if(!list.isEmpty() && email != null && !email.equals("") && !email.trim().equals("") && password != null && !password.equals("") && !password.trim().equals("")){
             //ignores multiple results
           foundEntity = list.get(0);
           session = request.getSession();
           session.setAttribute("user", foundEntity.getFamilyName()+", "+foundEntity.getFirstName());
           session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);

           return "home";
        }else{
            System.out.println("Empty? "+Boolean.toString(list.isEmpty()));
            System.out.println("Email "+email);
            System.out.println("Password "+password);
            map.addAttribute("error", "Incorrect Email/Password");
            return "login";
        }

    }
```

-- in home.jsp --

I can see the User value being displayed in the page.

But when i go to another page (using another controller), it redirects to login page. And I think its because the session attribute "user" is null. I put a condition if user is null, it will go back to login page.

-- another controller --

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Home(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) {
    HttpSession session= request.getSession();
     boolean isLogged= session.getAttribute("user")!=null;

       if(isLogged){
           return "home";
       }else{
           return "/index"; // redirect to login page if session is not established
       }
}

@RequestMapping("/list")
public String list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) {
    HttpSession session= request.getSession();
     boolean isLogged=session.getAttribute("user")!=null;

       if(isLogged){
            String searchTerm = request.getParameter("searchTerm");
            String paging = request.getParameter("paging");
            int page = 0; //pagination not yet working
            List<UsersModule> list = usersModuleService.getUsersList(searchTerm,
                    page);
                map.addAttribute("usersList", list);
                return "usersmodule/list"; // go to users list page

       }else{

           return "/index"; // redirect to login page if session is not established
       }
}
```

-- list.jsp--

When i go to another page like this, I cannot see the User value and i am redirected to the login page.

I cannot solve how to keep the session attribute values when going to another webpages. I have tried all the resources i could find but it still the same. :(

Comment: How did you get HttpServletRequest?

Comment: wait, i will post the full code.

Comment: Do you see `home` page after successful login, or `Home` method redirects you to index right after login?

Comment: yes i can see the home page after logged in and then when i clicked to go to another page, it redirects to login page.

Comment: Looks like `loginModuleService.getLoginDetails` returns empty list

Comment: its not empty cause after i logged in, in the home page, i can see my user name displayed.

Comment: I think i cant pass session attributes to another controller

Comment: Off cause, you can. I did many time. Try to debug your code and compare session objects. Is it same one? You can insert `System.out.println(session)` in `logIn` and in other method where you get redirect to `index`. In output you will see something like `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@b1e0a32`. Code after `@` is unique object identifier. Compare this code from different methods, and you can find out - is this session same one or not.

Comment: if not the same, how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

public String logIn(HtppSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map){}

define HttpSession as a variable of login method.